# How make dropdown using mysql database, when structure like this?

Tags: php, mysql, dropdown

How to make dropdown using database sql? when like this structure. im confuse how to get dropdown using this structure

```
<?php
$sqlo = "SELECT * from outlet";
$queryo = $dbh -> prepare($sqlo);
$queryo->execute();
$results=$queryo->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);{
?>
<div class="col-md-1">
    <div class="position-relative form-group"><label for="outlet"> Kategori <span style="color:red"> *</span></label>
        <select name="outlet" id="outlet" class="form-control">

            <option value="<?php htmlentities($result->nameoutlet); ?>"><?php htmlentities($result->nameoutlet); }?></option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

dbh has declare in config.php, in config just connection into loacalhost.

```
<?php
// DB credentials.
define('DB_HOST','localhost');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASS','');
define('DB_NAME','ereport');
// Establish database connection.
try
{
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME,DB_USER, DB_PASS,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    exit("Error: " . $e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

Comment: What's the exact problem with the given code? What does not work yet, and what have you tried to get it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're trying to use the DB to fill a dropdown menu? It's important to know the difference between a frontend language and a backend language. [This might help you.](https://careerfoundry.com/en/blog/web-development/whats-the-difference-between-frontend-and-backend/)

As for your problem, you'll want to use a foreach loop.

```
    <?php

    $options = '';
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $safe_value = htmlentities($result->nameoutlet);
        $options .= "<option value='$safe_value'>$safe_value</option>";
    }

    ?>

    <div class="col-md-1">
        <div class="position-relative form-group">
            <label for="outlet"> Kategori <span style="color:red"> *</span></label>
            <select name="outlet" id="outlet" class="form-control">
                <?= $options ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: thankyou i ll try, cuz in univercity i didn't get mean frontend and backend language

Answer (score 0):

You have to run `foreach` loop. Insert this code:

```
<pre>
    <?php foreach ($results as $row) { ?>
      <option value="<?php echo htmlentities($row->nameoutlet); ?>"><?php echo htmlentities($row->nameoutlet); ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</pre>
```

Comment: i have done used that logic before ask, but it not work. thankyou for contribute